# dismissviewcontrolleranimated: completion: not found after upgrade to xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

After upgrading to xcode 4.5, I got a warning that dismissViewControllerAnimated is deprecated. I change the code to the recommended dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: and I get a warning that dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: is not found.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste error.

The problem was that I left Modal in the call when I replaced it with dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:completed: instead of dismissViewControllerAnimated:completed: